# How to resolve docker machine ip address to a DNS?

Tags: dns, docker

Still fairly new to Docker. I have a docker machine that is created using VirtualBox which is currently broadcasting on an IP address (e.g. 192.168.99.100). I was wondering if there is a way to resolve the IP address to a DNS so instead of typing in 192.168.99.100 in my web browser I can use the name I assigned it? I've tried to ssh into the machine and edit the /etc/resolv.conf but that does not appear to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're mac or linux modifying `/etc/hosts` should do the trick.

Comment: I am on windows 7 and working with the docker-toolkit/docker quickstart terminal

Comment: I think it's `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` there, but I haven't been on Windows in a while.

Comment: Thanks @wogsland that did the trick. At first I was editing the /etc/host in the docker terminal itself but that was not it.